# Using LSTM for large text

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, nlp, lstm, kaggle

I have a dataset for detecting fake news that i got from kaggle( https://www.kaggle.com/c/fake-news/data ).
I want to use LSTM for the classification

The mean length of words in a single article is about 750 words. I have tried to remove punctuation, stop words, removed numbers. Preprocessing the text is also taking a very long time.

I'd like a method to feed large text into the LSTM using keras. What should i do to reduce computation time and not lose a lot of accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things you could try to  speed things up:

### 1. Use CUDNN version of LSTM

It is usually faster, check available layers [here](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) `keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` is what you are after.

### 2. Use `Conv1d` to create features

You can use 1 dimensional convolution with `kernel_size` specifying how many words should be taken into account and `stride` specifying the jump of moving window. For `kernel_size=3` and `stride=3`, `padding="SAME"` it would drop your dimensionality three times.

You may stack more convolutional layers.

On top of that you can still employ `LSTM` normally.

### 3. Drop LSTM altogether

You may go with 1d convolutions and pooling for classification, RNNs are not the only way.

On the upside: you will not encounter vanishing gradients (could be mitigated a little by Bidirectional LSTM as well).

On the downside: you will lose strict dependence between words, though it shouldn't be much of a problem for binary classification (I suppose it's your goal).

Comment: Thanks:). I tried conv+lstm, was getting pretty low accuracy, though only using CNN is getting me good accuracy.